# Minimal-edge graph with diameter 2 and bounded max degree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider all connected simple graphs with diameter $d = 2$ and maximal vertex degree $\Delta$. In my particular practical case $\Delta = 4$, but general problem is much more interesting — probably there exists a research on general case.

I know that, given $d = 2$ and $\Delta = 4$, the maximal number of vertices in the proper graph is $V = 15$ (the corresponding graph is [K3 * C5](http://www-ma4.upc.es/~comellas/delta-d/desc_g/desc_g2.html#42)). The question is: given $V$, how can one find the proper $V$-vertex graph with *minimal* number of *edges*?

I wrote the simple brute-force program and found the answer for all $V \le 8$. But calculating it further using this approach is going to take a tremendous amount of time, so I decided to ask the community for any advices or links to researches. Thank you for any assistance.

P.S. Sorry, if my English wasn't understandable enough.

P.P.S. Firstly I asked this question at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66384/minimal-edge-graph-with-diameter-2-and-bounded-max-degree), but later I realized that it would be more appropriate here. Sorry for redundancy.

Comment: So if I read correctly, your problem is the following: Given Delta, d, n, find the graph with diameter d, and max degree Delta on n vertices with the fewest edges?

Comment: @utdiscant Yes, exactly. And in case there would be no results on the general problem, I'll be thankful just for the case d = 2, Delta = 4.

Comment: For the minimal number of edges, if you require at least one vertex have degree $\Delta$, how about a star with $\Delta$ points?

Comment: What's $K3*C5$?

Comment: @Chris, $K_3$ is a triangle, $C_5$ is a cycle of length 5, and for the product, take three little pentagons, and join each vertex in each pentagon to the corresponding vertex in each of the other pentagons.

Comment: $K_3 * C_5$ has diameter 3, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the [graph diameter problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_the_largest_known_graphs_of_a_given_diameter_and_maximal_degree).  You'll probably find your answer in the realm of Distance Regular Graphs, since minimal/maximal solutions in graph theory tend to have a lot of symmetry.